# Getting 'None' Output when reading from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Here is the code I am using:

```
import csv
import os

filename = "studentinfo.csv"
filedir = ""
csv_file = os.path.join(filedir, filename)

names = []
ages = []
emails = []

with open(csv_file) as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        names.append(row.get('name'))
        ages.append(row.get('age'))
        emails.append(row.get('email'))

print(names, ages, emails)
```

and this is the CSV file:

```
name, age, email
fin harris, 14,email1
harvey green, 14, email2
```

I am getting this output:

```
['fin harris', 'harvey green'] [None, None] [None, None]
```

Why am I getting the output None?

Comment: Remove all the whitespaces from both the header line and the data lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of whitespaces before column name. You can use 
`row.get(' age')` or remove whitespaces from column names.

Comment: The better solution is to remove the whitespaces. If not for the csv """standards""" then for the consistency of the column names. Whitespaces should also be removed from the data rows